# Eigen, function of RowXpr

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I am using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), and am currently trying to write a function to operate on rows of a matrix. I've followed the [guidelines in the docs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html) but nothing I try compiles (with either clang or g++); I'm at my wits end. How should one actually write functions which will take a RowXpr?

For reference, here is what I have tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

constexpr Eigen::StorageOptions Order = ColMajor;

using vect_t = Matrix<double, 1, 3, Order>;
using matr_t = Matrix<double, Dynamic, 3, Order>; 

#define FUNC 3

#if FUNC == 1

vect_t func(const vect_t& f)
{
    return f;
}

#elif FUNC == 2

vect_t func(const Ref<vect_t>& f)
{
    return f;
}

#elif FUNC == 3

template<class D> vect_t func(const MatrixBase<D>& f)
{
    return f;
}

#endif

int main()
{
    matr_t M = matr_t::Random(5,3);
    cout << M << endl;
    cout << func( M.row(2) ) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

**Edit:**

With clang (version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4) the error I get is as below. The error is comparable with g++.

```
dan@dan-laptop:~/workspace/scratch$ clang++ eigen_func_test.cpp -I /home/dan/Downloads/eigen_3.3.3/ --std=c++11 && ./a.out 
In file included from eigen_func_test.cpp:2:
In file included from /home/dan/Downloads/eigen_3.3.3/Eigen/Core:436:
/home/dan/Downloads/eigen_3.3.3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:899:7: error: static_assert failed
      "INVALID_MATRIX_TEMPLATE_PARAMETERS"
  ...EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT((EIGEN_IMPLIES(MaxRowsAtCompileTime==1 && MaxColsAtCompileTime!=1, (Options&RowMajor)==RowMajor)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/dan/Downloads/eigen_3.3.3/Eigen/src/Core/util/StaticAssert.h:32:40: note: expanded from macro
      'EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT'
    #define EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(X,MSG) static_assert(X,#MSG);
                                       ^             ~
/home/dan/Downloads/eigen_3.3.3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:535:7: note: in instantiation of member function
      'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3> >::_check_template_params' requested here
      _check_template_params();
      ^
/home/dan/Downloads/eigen_3.3.3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:379:9: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3>
      >::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 3, 0, -1, 3>, 1, 3, false> >' requested here
      : Base(other.derived())
        ^
eigen_func_test.cpp:32:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 3, 0,
      1, 3>::Matrix<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 3, 0, -1, 3>, 1, 3, false> >' requested here
        return f;
               ^
eigen_func_test.cpp:41:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'func<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 3, 0, -1, 3>, 1, 3, false> >' requested here
        cout << func( M.row(2) ) << endl;
                ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: What compiler errors are you getting? The only two things that I see that might be in question is that your function template is expecting to return a type of `vect_t` and you are return a `const ref` of `MatrixBase<T>`. Also in your main function the other thing in question might be the fact that you are trying to print `M` which is a `matr_t` type and without looking at the documentation I do not know if they have an overloaded output stream operator for it.

Comment: Hi @FrancisCugler, it's nothing to do with the cout, this line works if I comment out the function calls. I've added an example of the compiler output.

Comment: Okay I can now see that it's not coming from the stream operators but it is coming from the template parameter itself. This appears to be coming from your function template. I can add an answer not as so much to answer the question because I do not know this library, but I can do what I can to try to give you some insight on what I believe the compiler is trying to do with your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the part highlighted by clang

```
EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT((EIGEN_IMPLIES(MaxRowsAtCompileTime==1 && MaxColsAtCompileTime!=1, (Options&RowMajor)==RowMajor)
```

you see that, if a matrix has one row at compile time and more than one column, it must be RowMajor. That means, if you set `Order = RowMajor` or just leave out the `, Order` in

```
using vect_t = Matrix<double, 1, 3, Order>;
```

your code should compile fine (it looks like everything else are just follow-up errors).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what is causing your compiler error directly but from what you have shown in your source code as well as your compiler errors. This is the part of the compiler error message that I'm basing this off of.

> ```
> /home/dan/Downloads/eigen_3.3.3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:899:7: error: static_assert failed
>   "INVALID_MATRIX_TEMPLATE_PARAMETERS"
> ```

So when looking at the source code you are trying to use the `#define func3`

that you have declared as such:

> ```
> template<class D> vect_t func(const MatrixBase<D>& f) {
>     return f;
> }
> ```

with the using directives that you have declared as:

> ```
> constexpr Eigen::StorageOptions Order = ColMajor;
>
> using vect_t = Matrix<double, 1, 3, Order>;
> using matr_t = Matrix<double, Dynamic, 3, Order>;
> ```

So let's expand this to the full form to see what the compiler is trying to parse or deduce as your parameters and return type.

```
template<class D>
Matrix<double, 1, 3, constexpr Eigen::StorageOptions Order = ColMajor>
func( const MatrixBase<D>& f ) {
    return f;
}
```

Then in your main you use this with:

```
int main() {
    // matr_t M = matr_t::Random(5,3);
    Matrix<double, Dynamic, 3, constexpr Eigen::StorageOptions Order = ColMajor> M 
      = Matrix<double, Dynamic, 3, constexpr Eigen::StorageOptions Order = ColMajor>::Random(5, 3);

    // Then you call your function passing it this:
    std::cout << func( M.row(2) ) << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

`func()` is returning `Matrix<double, 1, 3, Order>;`
and it takes `const MatrixBase<D>&`
however it appears you are passing it: `M.row(2)`
that is constructed from: `Matrix<double, Dynamic, 3, constexpr Eigen::StorageOptions Order = ColMajor>::Random(5, 3)`

In the function itself you are returning `f` which happens to be
the function's `const ref` of `MatrixBase<D>` parameter yet the declaration is expecting to return a `Matrix<double, 1, 3, Order>`

So I think the compiler is having a hard time trying to convert a
`Matrix<double, Dynamic, 3, Order>` to a `Matrix<double, 1, 3, Order>`

Maybe this will help you to understand the compiler error a little better; as you can see when you look at the rest of the compilation error message you can tell that this is evident when it is trying to do the specializations of this template.